# Windows Phone Periodic Task Synchronization Async Methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-8

I am attempting to make use of a Periodic Background Task on a Windows Phone 8 app.  I want to use a xml file to serialize state information between the foreground app and the background task.

I read that you should use a Mutex to synchronize access to the file.  However, I run into issues using it, because I need to call await in the method that I use the Mutex in (to read and write data to a file).  This causes my app to lock up when I call Mutex.Release, since it is being released on a different thread.  Any ideas how to handle this?

```
    public async Task WriteState(BackgroundTaskState state)
    {            
        using (var m = new Mutex(false, BackgroundTaskState.MutexName))
        {

            try
            {
                m.WaitOne();

                using (var stream = await GetFileStreamForWriting())
                {
                    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BackgroundTaskState));
                    xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, state);
                    await stream.FlushAsync();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                m.ReleaseMutex();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: no need to call FlushAsync when wrapped in a using. Flush is already called within the Dispose method. Where is a handy file to use in your WP apps http://codepaste.net/63vh4o

Comment: Even if I don't use FushAsync, I still need to call await GetFileStreamForWriting() to get a stream to the file.

Comment: Do you? Check out the file I suggested

Comment: Yeah, i checked out the file.  The problem is that i need to use the StorageFile classes instead of IsolatedStorageFile because I plan to use the code on WinRT as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Mutex` must only be released by the same thread that acquired it so you cannot using it with `await`. You can use [`Semaphore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) to achieve the same result, since they are not bounded to ant particular thread.

```
semaphore.WaitOne();
await Task.Delay(2); // Your async call
semaphore.Release();
```